# Problema con el argumento Lista en una Función al llamarla dos veces

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy tratando de definir la siguiente función con Python,

```
def caja(cosas=[]):        
    cosas.append("lapiz") 
    cosas.append("martillo")
    cosas.append("azulejos")   
    return cosas

>>> caja()
["lapiz", "martillo", "azulejos"]
```

Aquí viene el problema, cuando vuelvo a llamar la función `caja()` en vez de crearme una lista vacia, me agrega los datos a la lista existente.

```
>>> caja()
["lapiz", "martillo", "azulejos","lapiz", "martillo", "azulejos"]
```

Alguien sabe como funciona Python en este aspecto? Los argumentos solo se evalúan una vez en el momento de declarar la función?

Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu pregunta es un tema bastante recurrente para todos los que empezamos en Python viniendo de otro lenguaje. Vamos primero con la solución: el modo correcto de hacer lo que tienes pensado es así:

```
def caja(cosas=None):
    if caja is None:
       caja = []
    cosas.append("lapiz") 
    cosas.append("martillo")
    cosas.append("azulejos")   
    return cosas
```

#### ¿Ahora bien, cual es la explicación de este aparentemente "antinatural" comportamiento?

Por empezar este comportamiento se da únicamente con valores default "mutables", en tu caso, una lista lo es, con strings esto no sucede.

En Python una función es un objeto más, por lo que en realidad cuando una la define, está creando  un nuevo objeto. Los valores default funcionan de alguna manera como datos propios del objeto función. Veamos que ocurre a partir del `def` y en las invocaciones posteriores:

Al definir la función:

- Se crea un nuevo objeto función apuntado al nombre `caja` dentro del namespace del modulo
- Se evalúa la función: por cada valor default, se crea un objeto, en este caso una lista vacía [] que será un dato propio del objeto función creado, por comodidad la llamaremos `lista_valor_default`

La primera vez que ejecutamos la función:

- Al no pasar parámetros lo que hace Python es asociar la variable/objeto interna `cosas` al objeto `lista_valor_default`
  que se definió al crearse la función, la primera vez el comportamiento será el esperado, agregamos datos, pero no a `cosas` (referencia) sino al objeto `lista_valor_default`

La siguiente llamada sin parámetros:

- `lista_valor_default` ahora ya no es una lista vacía por lo que `cosas` apuntara a una lista con los elementos de la llamada anterior, y seguiremos agregando más elemento a `lista_valor_default`.

#### Demostración:

El siguiente código sirve para entender el comportamiento comentado:

```
def prueba(lista=[]):
  falsanuevalista = lista
  falsanuevalista.append("Agrego el valor: {0}".format(len(falsanuevalista)))
  print("id lista: {0} id falsanuevalista: {1}".format(id(lista), id(falsanuevalista)))

  return falsanuevalista

print(prueba())
print(prueba())

id lista: 140651642166280 id falsanuevalista: 140651642166280
['Agrego el valor: 0']
id lista: 140651642166280 id falsanuevalista: 140651642166280
['Agrego el valor: 0', 'Agrego el valor: 1']
```

Vemos que en todo momento el `id` de `lista` (valor default) es el mismo de la variable interna `falsanuevalista`, por lo que se demuestra que los `append` actúan sobre sobre la lista default.

Hay varias alternativas, la que te comenté más arriba suele ser la más adecuada, pero eventualmente podrías dejar tu función tal como está definida pero el truco sería forzar una copia de la lista default a nueva variable interna y retornar ésta, por ejemplo así:

```
def caja(cosas=[]):
    nueva = cosas[:]   # El slice es una forma de crear una nueva lista      
    # nueva = list(cosas)   # o usando el constructor     
    nueva.append("lapiz") 
    nueva.append("martillo")
    nueva.append("azulejos")   
    return nueva
```

Para más info, te recomiendo [este](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/) articulo

Comment: Muchas gracias tío! Ahora lo entiendo! :)

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una solucion:

```
def caja():
  cosas=[]        
  cosas.append("lapiz")
  cosas.append("martillo")
  cosas.append("azulejos")
  return cosas
```

Como parametro estabas inicializando una variable, por eso no se vaciaba